# Show $\zeta(s)$ doesn't have a zero on interval $[0, 1]$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Let $\zeta$ be the Riemann zeta function, I am trying to show that it does not have a zero on the interval $[0, 1]$. I have tried using the extension of the $\zeta$ function to $Re(s)>0$ namely: 
$$ \zeta(s) = \frac{s}{s-1} - s\int_1^\infty \{x\}x^{-s-1}dx$$ 
However I could only bound this below by some negative constant which is clearly not helpful here...

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: use the *Dirichlet eta function*
$$\eta (s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}=1-\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{3^s}-\dots$$
which is valid for $\operatorname{Re} s>0$, and satisfies the relation
$$\eta(s)=({1-2^{1-s}})\zeta(s) $$

Comment: Sweet thanks, I suppose it is easy to see that $\eta(s)$ is positive on the given range given that $\eta(s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1}$

Comment: You can just notice that $1-1/2^s>0$, $1/3^s-1/4^s>0$, etc.

Comment: Given that the sum doesn't absolutely converge in this range are we allowed to re-arrange the sum like this?

Comment: But we aren't rearranging (i.e. permutating terms), we are only using the associative property, which holds for conditionally convergent series.